# Adding a username in Permalink in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am new in wordpress and I would like to know if there is a way to add a username in a permalink of the wordpress.

The permalink is like this

```
http://myname.com/memberpage
```

and I would to add a username in the permalink like this

```
http://myname.com/username/memberpage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your URL using this link Please check this link .

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-author-url-slug-and-base-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for answering but what I'm trying to do in the permalink is that I want to put a dynamic value after the 
http://myname.com/<-this part is dynamic->/memberpage

my permalink is  this 

http://myname.com/memberpage

the dynamic part are the users in the wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can give the custom url by yourself. 
In your case you can do something like this 
`<?php echo get_site_url().'/'.<username>.'/memberpage' ?>`
Where you can get the current username and other info using `<?php get_currentuserinfo(); ?>`
see this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo